# Html Parser - C# Regex html tags (div, img, a, h5 etc) plus attributes

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing, phrase

Html Parser - C# Regex html tags content >me im the content< (div, img, a, h5 etc)
the html tags are Closed in a number of different ways.

Why am doing this you might ask.  I have inherited prototype code to perform phrase replacement for example Home -> Casa. (Spanish).
As you can imagine i have quite a lot of phrases (350 and rising) such as "Add New Contact" which vary in length and word count.

First requirement: A Regex is required to pull out the tag content.
Output must be: 
    here is the content to be matched by the regex
This will allow me to further manipulate the string to allow me to perform phrase replacement.

Second Requirement:
    here is the content to be matched by the regex/>
A Regex is required to pull out the attribute tag content such as:
     
Output must be:

Please Please dont respond with use an HTML Agility Pack.  I have bespoke requirements that does not allow me to look at 
a: A Well formed document.
b. Client side XSL transforms
c. Xml Data islands which determine content.

```
string file = @"<html>
        <body>
            <input class='moth'>Add New Organisation  </>
<input class='moth'>Org&#160;role
 </>
         </body>
           </html>";

string searchText = "Add New Organisation";

<([\d\w]*)\b[^>]*>([\d\w\s]*?{0}[\d\w\s]*)
```

So can anyone help.  So far i have been using this regexp..

```
 var myContentMatches = new List<string>
            (Regex.Matches(file, regExpressionContent.ToString(),
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                | RegexOptions.Multiline)
            .Cast<Match>().Select(pp => pp.ToString()));
```

I am trying not to overload the question here.  Any further information required please ask.  I have been banging my head against the speed and correct matching on this for some time now.

Comment: I don't understand how the three requirements you state preclude you from using the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: The HAP deals with malformed documents, doesn't do client side XSL transforms, will parse XML Data islands as they are.

Comment: It's easy to do this with HAP. Excluding the correct answer without a valid reason is dumb. Parsing HTML with regex is very dumb.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a regular language, and cannot be parsed with Regular Expressions.  I do not believe that there is a realistic solution to your problem that does not leverage an existing library for parsing HTML.

This is one of the most up-voted question/answer combos on StackOverflow, and I suggest you read it: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Backed into a corner much :( Check.  I have since learn't of another method in which i need to test tomorrow.  I am currently using a httpModule written in c#.  I am going to attempt to override the flush method and ensure that i have the full reponse stream as such the full html document and then perform my replacement on the string.  HAP might be an option back on the table at this point.  However does anyone know how HAP deals with partial ajax postbacks from say an ASP:UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this question, using the HAP has solved a proportion of my requirements.  Thank you all for your suggestions.